# Gulp imagemin optimization removes svg symbol

Tags: javascript, svg, optimization, gulp, gulp-imagemin

This is the first time I use Gulp task-runner or any kind of task-runner. I hope I state my problem in an understandable way.

I have an svg file named `svg-system.svg` which contains:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <!-- facebook icon -->
    <symbol id="facebook" role="img" aria-labelledby="title desc" viewBox="0 0 9.3 20">
        <title id="title">Logo af Facebook</title>
        <desc id="desc">Logoet bruges til link indikator for at tilgå vores Facebook side eller dele os.</desc>
        <path d="M9.3,6.5L8.9,10H6.1c0,4.5,0,10,0,10H2c0,0,0-5.5,0-10H0V6.5h2V4.2C2,2.6,2.8,0,6.2,0l3.1,0v3.4
        c0,0-1.9,0-2.2,0c-0.4,0-0.9,0.2-0.9,1v2.1H9.3z"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

And I would like to compress the file / optimize it for my dist to save some kilobytes.

My confiq in `gulpfile.js` looks like this:

```
gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/images/**/*.+(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)')
    // Caching images that ran through imagemin
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({
        options: {
            optimizationLevel: 3,
            progessive: true,
            interlaced: true,
            removeViewBox:false,
            removeUselessStrokeAndFill:false,
            cleanupIDs:false
        }
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
});
```

When I run the task it outputs my `svg-system.svg` with this content only:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"/>
```

Any suggestions or have you seen this issue yourself and fixed it? Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right general idea: setting `cleanupIDs` to `false` will indeed keep the `<symbol>` around. However the way you're doing it is wrong.

You're trying to pass an options object to `imagemin()`. While `gulp-imagemin` does in fact have an `options` argument, it [only supports the `verbose` option](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin#options). None of the options you specify are passed along to `svgo`.

You need to explicitly pass those options to the `svgo` plugin. The way you do this is honestly pretty weird and complicated, but here you go:

```
imagemin([
  imagemin.svgo({
    plugins: [
      { optimizationLevel: 3 },
      { progessive: true },
      { interlaced: true },
      { removeViewBox: false },
      { removeUselessStrokeAndFill: false },
      { cleanupIDs: false }
   ]
 }),
 imagemin.gifsicle(),
 imagemin.jpegtran(),
 imagemin.optipng()
])
```

Comment: Thx for your time, I tried like this https://jsfiddle.net/4t2kyj5z/ but it still compresses the svg to oblivion as postet in my question :P

Comment: That's because of `gulp-cache`. You need to [clear the cache](https://github.com/jgable/gulp-cache#clearing-the-cache).

Comment: Hmm, tried, still not doing the job :/ Here is gulpfile.js in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4t2kyj5z/1/

Comment: Try removing `gulp-cache` entirely to isolate the problem.

Comment: It worked perfect now, when I isolated the problem as you stated. So the cache made the problems. I read somewhere, when your app will get big enough with many images, making a build to get the dist files will take very long time, if you have many images. I had 2 images, and it toke like 2 sec. Do you use cache?

Comment: I've never used `gulp-cache`, but I have used [`gulp-changed`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-changed). The difference is that `gulp-cache` stores its cache somewhere in the file system. `cache.clearAll()` is supposed to clear this. No idea why it doesn't for you. `gulp-changed` on the other hand just checks if your images have changed since the last build. To recreate an image that hasn't changed you just need to delete it in your `dist/images` folder.